# Warning: Undefined variable $logo_image_height_html in

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

In the mobile page footer appear the following text:
Warning: Undefined variable $logo_image_height_html in /home/……./www/www/wp-content/plugins/td-composer/mobile/footer.php on line 79
How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Line 79:

```html
$buffy .= '<a href="' . esc_url(home_url( '/' )) . '" aria-label="Logo"><img src="' . $td_footer_logo . '" alt="' . $td_footer_logo_alt . '" title="' . $td_footer_logo_title . '" ' . $logo_image_width_html . $logo_image_height_html . '/></a>';
```

Comment: This is a better question for the plugin developer, since you *technically* shouldn't have to fix this. If you do fix it, then you risk your fix being overwritten if the plugin is ever updated. I would put in a support question for the plugin developer.

Comment: This feels like a case where the plugin developer hasn't updated their code for php 8. Unfortunately I didn't see `td-composer` listed on the Wordpress site. If that plugin is no longer supported, I suspect that you will have to go through the code and find everywhere that variable is used and make sure it is declared as `global`. (I have had to repair global variables for a couple of other old plugins.) Or consider finding an alternative that is still supported.